# Can hoverEffect in visionOS have a custom color?

Tags: hover, visionos

I'm trying to set a custom color for my hover effects but the only customization I'm able to make so far is on the shape of the hover glow, like this.-

```
.contentShape(.hoverEffect, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
.hoverEffect()
```

Is this even possible in `visionOS`?